# Multiple criteria filtering in single column, criteria not always present in datasheet

Tags: arrays, vba, filtering, criteria

I am trying to filter a column using 4 separate criteria.  I have working code when I use only two criter by doing the following:

```
Worksheets("Table1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*crit1*", _
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*crit2*"
```

In the above case, crit1 and crit2 are always present within field 3.

I want to add two aditional crit, crit3 and crit4.  I've tried the following, and cannot get it to work:

```
Worksheets("Table1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("*crit1*", "*crit2*", _
                                    "*crit3*", "*crit4*"), _
                                    Operator:=xlOr
```

Also, it seems to me that this will break if one of the criteria is not present in the area?  I.e, a dataset that is missing any occurrences of crit3.

Any help in doing this would be great!

Thanks,
Chris

UPDATE:  Thank you dwirony!  Took some messing around with, but i have it working now.  I don't really understand why I needed to make the changes in Set sht row and the filter array row, but code is doing exactly what I want it to now.  Appreciate the help!

```
    Sub AutoFilterWorkaround()
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim filterarr As Variant, tofindarr As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("Table1")
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'List the parts of the words you need to find here
    tofindarr = Array("crit1", "crit2", "crit3", "crit4")
    
    ReDim filterarr(0 To 0)
    j = 0
    
    For k = 0 To UBound(tofindarr)
    
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 3).Value, tofindarr(k)) > 0 Then
                filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 3).Value
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve filterarr(0 To j)
            End If
        Next i
    
    Next k
    
    'Filter on array
    Worksheets("Table1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(filterarr), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: it looks similar, but can't get this to work, i'll keep playing with it

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've modified it for your code - just replace crit1, 2, 3 and 4 with your actual criteria:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub AutoFilterWorkaround()
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim filterarr As Variant, tofindarr As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'List the parts of the words you need to find here
    tofindarr = Array("crit1", "crit2", "crit3", "crit4")
    
    ReDim filterarr(0 To 0)
    j = 0
    
    For k = 0 To UBound(tofindarr)
    
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 3).Value, tofindarr(k)) > 0 Then
                filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 3).Value
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve filterarr(0 To j)
            End If
        Next i
    
    Next k
    
    'Filter on array
    sht.Range("$C$1:$C$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(filterarr), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting run-time error '9': Subscript out of range :/

If i update Table1 to Sheet1 in Set sht row, i get a different error: Run-time error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed.  and it highlights the final Filter on array line

Comment: maybe it is due to there being characters before and after the "crit1"?  In my first code i use wildcards to account for the different potential  character strings before and after.

Comment: @Chris Shouldn't matter, this uses `InStr` to determine if the criteria is in any part of the cell. Are you sure the values you're looking for are in column C? Where is the header row on your document? And are you sure there are already filters on the dataset?

Comment: it is working now! i updated my post with my final code.